# Looking for a simple tool to annotate screenshots

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

It seems that the author used a tool - other than SnagIt - to annotate this screen shot:

[image]

`[http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-92/4617.snippetizerinfo.png]`

Does anybody know if there is a **simple** tool to create this type of annotations?

I know Illustrator or Gimp can do this, but I am looking for a simple tool to do this is seconds without ninja skills.

Thank you

Comment: Irfanview comes with an edit plugin, and sometimes I use it to add comments. There are many other alternatives (e.g. see [here](http://www.ezvid.com/5_free_snagit_alternative) or [here](http://superuser.com/questions/33244/free-tool-like-snagit-which-can-capture-scrolling-window) or [here](http://lifehacker.com/5880928/the-best-screen-capture-tool-for-windows))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot is from Skitch, an Evernote product.  Beware though - it is VERY buggy and generally a poor user experience.  I would not recommend it.

Comment: Hi Karen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks Karen. I've just tried and installed it. You are right. It might take a few more versions for Skitch to become useful. Once I draw something, I can't change it. Only undo is available.

Answer (score 2):

When I was teaching computers overseas I used OpenOffice.org for stuff like this. It comes with Writer and Draw. Most things you can just import the image into Writer and use the Draw functions from within there. It works very well.

Can setup connection points for arrows and lines, adjust colors, add text. Really was happy with it.

Comment: There is also Paint, which is oh so very very simple. I think a person would crack from frustration though, I second the open office suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) for a few years now. It is free and available at sourceforge.net. Has these functions and many upload plugins. And is stable. Runs only on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [Evernote](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/evernote%20web%20clipper), which I use. The shadings on the type and the arrows are recognizable.